# Clams, Pearls and Conditional Probability

Tags: probability

I can't figure this one out, maybe it's a matter of semantics, but here's my question (translated from Swedish) with thoughts.

> On a coral reef there are plenty of clams. It is estimated that $25\%$ are pearl clams and $75\%$ are sand clams. Half the pearl clams contain pearls while the sand clams are always empty. a) Determine the probability that a captured clam is empty. (7/8) b) A captured clam is found to be empty. Determine the conditional probability that a pearl clam has been caught. (1/7)

Let $E$ be the event that a pearl clam is caught, $F$ a sand clam, and $G$ the event that the clam contains a pearl, so that $P(E)=1/4$, $P(F)=3/4$, $P(G|E)=1/2$ and $P(G|F)=0$. Then the first question asks for $P(G^c) = 1-P(G) = 1-(P(G|E)P(E)+P(G|F)P(F)) = 1-1/8$, so far so good.

For the second question, my first thought was $P(E|G^c)=P(G^c|E)P(E)/P(G^c)=(2/7)P(G^c|E)$, but then I'm stuck. Any advice on what to do next? Thanks.

Comment: Well if you know that $P(G|E)=1/2$, then what is $P(G^C|E)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re essentially done: you’re missing only $P(G^c\mid E)$, but that’s known to be $\frac12$, since half of the pearl clams contain pearls.

Note that instead of applying Bayes’ theorem formally, you can work it out informally from first principles. By essentially the same argument that you used in the first part of the problem you know that $\frac78$ of the clams are empty. You also know that those empty clams comprise the $\frac34=\frac68$ of the clams that are sand clams together with the $\frac18$ of the clams that are empty pearl clams. Thus, for each empty pearl clam there are $6$ sand clams, so the empty pearl clams make up $\frac17$ of the population of empty clams, and the desired probability is $\frac17$.

Comment: Thanks! Regarding $P(G^c|E)=1/2$, I suppose then that $P(G^c|E)=1-P(G|E)$; could you show this? Intuitively it seems right, but I can't prove it. Edit: I can show $P(A|B^c)=1-P(A|B)$ by repeated conditioning, but not "the other way around".

Comment: @Erik: You’re welcome. Since $P(E)\ne 0$, and $G$ and $G^c$ are disjoint, I’d argue that $$P(G^c\mid E)+P(G\mid E)=\frac{P(G^c\cap E)}{P(E)}+\frac{P(G\cap E)}{P(E)}= \frac{P(G^c\cap E)+P(G\cap E)}{P(E)}=\frac{P((G^c\cup G)\cap E}{P(E)}= \frac{P(E)}{P(E)}=1\;.$$

Answer (score 1):

We just have to calculate the probability the clam is empty and is a pearl clam divided by the probability the clam is empty.

This is:

$$\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{8}}{\dfrac{7}{8}}=\dfrac{1}{7}$$